# Add Drools logger to Thorntail logging fraction

Tags: drools, thorntail

I'm trying to configure Drools SLF4J logging to write to the Thorntail logging fraction, how to I tell Thorntail to use `org.drools` in say `DEBUG` level?

Accoring to the [Drools docs](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_logging), I should configure the name to be `org.drools` and set my level, examples are provided for Logback and Log4J but I'd like to know how to use the Thorntail Logging fraction.  According to the [Thorntail logging docs](https://docs.thorntail.io/2.4.0.Final/#enabling-logging_thorntail) and [Reference](https://docs.thorntail.io/2.4.0.Final/#_logging_3) I should use square brackets to escape the identifier, but I'm not sure where to put this.  My rules are firing as expected but I'd like to see the Drools debug outputs as well.

I've configured the Thorntail maven plugin in my pom as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <!-- Network config for Docker containers -->
      <swarm.bind.address>0.0.0.0</swarm.bind.address>
      <java.net.preferIPv4Stack>true</java.net.preferIPv4Stack>
      <!-- Increase logging level -->
      <thorntail.logging>FINE</thorntail.logging>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>package</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've also added the following dependencies:

```xml
...
<!-- Thorntail JEE Dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
  <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Drools dependencies for starting a KIE Container to process rules -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Add Drools core for rule processing -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

I've created `src/main/resources/logging.properties` with the following content and even though I get plenty of `resteasy` and `undertow` `DEBUG` outputs, I don't get any Drools-specific output even though my rules are firing.

```
thorntail.logging.loggers.[org.drools].level=DEBUG
```

I've also tried adding `src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml` with the following content but with no luck.

```
thorntail:
  logging:
    loggers:
      org.drools:
        level: DEBUG
```

Comment: The last bit, `project-defaults.yml` with this logging configuration, looks totally correct. The only thing that comes to mind is that I sometimes had troubles with different log level names in JUL vs. JBoss Log Manager. Can you try `FINE`, `FINEST` and `TRACE` instead of `DEBUG`? It's a long shot, but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Thanks @Ladicek, I can't explain how this is now working but I was developing inside a Maven Docker container that I've now rebuilt and all logs are coming through as expected without both ```logging.properties``` and ```project-defaults.yml```, just with the Thorntail maven plugin configured as above!

Comment: Glad you solved it. Thinking about it more, the last 2 pieces (system property and `project-defaults.yml`) should do the same. The `thorntail.logging` system property you add in `pom.xml` enables default logging for all categories, so you get a lot more output.